# Reset total sum if input changes with jquery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of inputs that i'll be using to set values (0 to 100).
The total values from those inputs can't be more than 100, i have this done and it's working, but i need a way to subtract the total if i change one of those inputs and the total becomes < 100

Here's one example for what i have so far:

```
var soma_total = 0; 
jQuery(function($){
    $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function(){ 

        var valor = $(this).val();
        valorPorcentagem = valor;   
            eE = procPorcentagem(valorPorcentagem);

            eE = Math.ceil(eE);

            valorPorcentagem = parseInt(valorPorcentagem);

            if((parseInt(valorPorcentagem) + soma_total) > 100)
                valorPorcentagem = 100 - soma_total;
                $(this).val(valorPorcentagem);
                soma_total += valorPorcentagem;
console.log(soma_total);
                $('#final_sum').append('<li>'+soma_total+'</li>');

        });
    });
});

function procPorcentagem(entradaUsuario){
var resultadoPorcem = (entradaUsuario * 48) / 100;
return resultadoPorcem;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2fo1vfn/1/)

Help please, thanks!

Comment: can you give a example? what you mean "i need a way to subtract the total if i change one of those inputs and the total becomes < 100"?

Comment: @huanfeng, like, if i set the input values in order 50,50, the last input will always be 0 because the total can't be more than 100, but if i change my mind and edit to 50,40, the script dont allow me to set 10 in the third input because the total it's already 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo might give you an idea on how to proceed:

```js
$(function() {
    $(':text').val(0).on('change', function(e) {
        var i = $(':text'),
            total = 0;
        i.each(function() {
            total += +this.value;
        });
        if( total > 100 ) {
            this.value -= (total - 100);
        }
        total = 0;
        i.each(function() {
            total += +this.value;
        });
        $('#final_sum').text( total );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
    <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
            
            <div id="final_sum">0</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i have like 400+ text inputs here, so i need to call them dinamically using $.each, also, try to use 50,40,20 in my example, the last input does not become 0, it adjust to match 100 in total.

Comment: Correct, you can use `.each()` method where applicable; all I am sharing is a concept. If you need an accurate answer, please clarify the requirements in your question. And give a few examples to further clarify. Please try 50, 40, 20 now

Comment: your code works like a charm in the snippet, when i try to implement it here, the last value does not adjust to fill 100, but i'll get your answer as correct and will check what's going on my code, thanks :)

Comment: Worked, the problem was because i was using each inside each, so i removed the first $.each and it worked, thanks a lot!